# Django configuration - connect url

Tags: python, django

How to configure web too django?
I have installed django and next step? htaccess on my folder domain? e.x i need some like this

```
"www.XXXX.com/hello"
```

but - `'error 404'`

```
bin/mojaapka/mojaapka  - urls, settings etc.
site-packages/django-1.5.1=py3.3.egg/django - django 
public_html/domain.xx.pl - domain
```

Comment: use `manage.py` to create a site and an application. run `manage.py runserver` to see it on localhost. read the documentation.

Comment: on localhost it is simple...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use something like Apache to host Django.

How-to is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/)

Or you need to provide more information, like what kind of server setup you are using.